# Is there a tile component available in MDL?

Tags: material-design-lite

I can't find any tile component in MDL on getmdl.io. The card component is well documented, but not the tile component.

Comment: They did not finish copying Modern GUI yet ;-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean [Grid Lists](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/grid-lists.html) instead of tiles. As far as I can tell there is no tile specification.

If this is the case, then you would need to combine the grid component and cards. This would get you most of the way there with a little extra custom code for card sizing and maybe shifting a few other bits around if needed.

Comment: Tiles are indirectly specified here https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage, e.g. "Tiles have square corners.", "Tiles have no more than two actions.",  "Grid tiles are a clean and lightweight way to present a gallery of images.".

Comment: That would be something where grid list would need to be implemented first, since it defines tile usage, then cards would be updated with a modifier to make them work within a the grid list component.

Answer (score 0):

I found something great when going through codepen the other day: http://codepen.io/zavoloklom/pen/wtApI.

```
<a class="tile tile-lg tile-sqr tile-red ripple-effect" href="#">
<span class="content-wrapper">
  <span class="tile-content">
    <span class="tile-img" style="background-image: url(http://www.google.com/design/images/design-minutes.png);"></span>
    <span class="tile-holder tile-holder-sm">
      <span class="title">Design Minutes</span>
    </span>
  </span>      
</span>
</a>
```

If you want to take your own approach.I suggest learning about the cell item and moving on from there: http://mdlhut.com/2015/07/understanding-the-mdl-grid/